# Is the connecting homomorphism unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

> *Theorem :* Given an exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow A
>  \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow  0$$ of
> chain/cochain exists a connecting homomorphism $\omega : H(C)
>  \longrightarrow H(A)$ of degree $1$ or $-1$ which induces a long exact
> sequence in homology or cohomology.

The construction of $\omega$ is quite explicit, in fact $\omega[\gamma] = \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a preimage of $\partial \beta$, where $\beta$ is the element such that $\beta \longmapsto \gamma \in C_n$.

Since in the proof one proves that doesn't depend on the choice of the $\gamma$ representing $[\gamma]$ and $\beta$ which goes to $\alpha$, could I conclude that whenever I find an explicit function, such that respect those requirements for specific elements, that function is $\omega$ indeed since in homology they are the same function ?

The question arises from the connecting homomorphism of the $Cf$ complex, where for the first time I noticed this kind of "uniqueness" to assert that in that scenario, the long exact sequence has $\omega = f_*$ as connecting homomorphism.

Any clarification or help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You repeat the definition of a function, and ask if every function which satisfies this definition is equal to that function. Of course.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Is not clear to me the costruction, whether the function is created on a chain level or directly homology level. If this is the first case, the functions defined on the chain complex are different ?

Comment: There is no function on the chain level - it is only a relation there.

Comment: Do note that the connecting homomorphism $\partial$ is _not_ uniquely determined by the requirement that it fit naturally into long exact sequences. For instance $-\partial$ works just as well.

Comment: @tcamps So it's unique except for the sign ?

Comment: @jacopoburelli I'm not sure. I think it will depend on precisely which category you're in. But I should re-emphasize that Martin is entirely correct: the standard definition given for $\partial$ does pick out a unique, well-defined map at the level of homology. One can give a chain-level map under the right circumstances if one is careful, but the sense in which it's unique at the chain level is more subtle (personlly, my preferred language for stating a uniqueness property would be the language of $\infty$-categories).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I believe you are asking is whether one can replace the connecting homomorphism $\partial : H_n(C) \to H_{n-1}(A)$ with some other homomorphism so that the sequence is still exact. If that's the question then yes, this is possible. For example, as noted in the comments and in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045594/connecting-homomorphism-is-determined-upto-a-sign-pm-1?rq=1), the homomorphism $-\partial : H_n(C) \to H_{n-1}(A)$ has the same kernel and same image as $\partial$, and so you could replace $\partial$ with $-\partial$ without affecting exactness.

But one could say more: if $h : H_n(C) \to H_n(C)$ is any automorphism that preserves $\text{kernel}(\partial)$ --- meaning that $h(\text{kernel}(\partial)) = \text{kernel}(\partial)$ --- then you could replace $\partial$ by $\partial \circ h$; and if in addition $k : H_{n-1}(A) \to H_{n-1}(A)$ is an automorphism that preserves $\text{image}(\partial)$ then you could replace $\partial$ by $k \circ h$; and you could put these together and replace $\partial$ by $k \circ \partial \circ h$. Each of these alterations keeps the sequence exact.

So, for example, additive inversion in any abelian group is an isomorphism that preserves all subgroups, and so replacing $\partial$ with $-\partial$ does not affect exactness of the sequence.

For a broader kind of example, let's consider the case where the homology groups in question are free abelian groups. Free abelian groups have **lots** of automorphisms, and so it might be quite easy to find lots of $h$'s and $k$'s. For a more specific example, suppose that $H_n(C) \approx \mathbb Z^\beta$ is a free abelian group of rank $\beta$ ($=$ the $n^\text{th}$ Betti number of $C$). It follows that
$$\text{Aut}(H_n(C)) \approx \text{Aut}(\mathbb Z^\beta) \approx \text{GL}_\beta(\mathbb Z)
$$
If in addition $H_{n-1}(Z)$ is free abelian then the subgroup $\text{kernel}(\partial)$ is a direct factor of some rank $r$, and by appropriate choice of basis there is a direct sum decomposition $H_n(C) \approx \mathbb Z^\beta \approx \mathbb Z^r \oplus \mathbb Z^{\beta-r}$ so that $\text{kernel}(\partial)$ is identified with the first direct summand. In this situation you can choose $h$ to be any invertible matrix of integers having all $0$'s in the upper right $r \times (\beta-r)$ block.

But there's a catch: one very important fact about the standard construction of the connecting homomorphism $\partial$ that you describe in your post is that it is a [natural transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) in the category theoretic sense. As explained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045594/connecting-homomorphism-is-determined-upto-a-sign-pm-1?rq=1), $-\partial$ is also a natural transformation. Undoubtedly if you choose $h$ and $k$ carelessly (rather than just choosing additive inversion) then you'll lose naturality.